# What kind of windowing system does Mac OS X use?

Tags: macos, windowing

What type of windowing system does Mac OS X use? Is it a modified X window system? Or something totally different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### OS X uses [Quartz Compositor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartz_Compositor)

along with the [Aqua](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aqua_%28user_interface%29) theme.

Comment: Really? I thought that that was the name they gave the 'look and feel' of it. Is this not the case?

Comment: @Mr. Man: Aqua is the theme (or look and feel) while Quartz Composer is the windowing system. I initially just had Aqua, which was incorrect.

Comment: 'Compositor' :)

Comment: Quartz *Compositor* is the name of the windowing system, actually; a bit picky, I s'pose, but Quartz Composer is technically something different. :) To further answer the question, the internal representation of windows is based on a PDF model.

Comment: Yeah, my brain heard something different then what my eyes were telling me. What's really embarrassing is the article has a nice big notation saying *"Not to be confused with [Quartz Composer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartz_Composer)"*.